# Issues Using Redux-Observable With Axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable

I'm trying to learn redux-observables but I seem to be having an issue getting my app to return data. I keep getting the error below and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or what the error actually means.

Error: TypeError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.get(...).map is not a function

Actions:

```
import { FETCH_DATA, FETCH_DATA_FAIL } from './constants';

export const fetchData = exampleData => ({
type: FETCH_DATA,
payload: { exampleData }
});

export const fetchDataFail = () => ({
type: FETCH_DATA_FAIL
});
```

EPIC:

```
 import 'rxjs';
 import { FETCH_DATA, FETCH_DATA_FAIL } from './constants';
 import { fetchData  } from './actions';
 import axios from 'axios';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
 import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

 export const exampleEpic = action$ =>
   action$.pipe(ofType(FETCH_DATA),
   mergeMap(action =>
     axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
       .map(response => fetchData(response))
       .catch(error => Observable.ofType(FETCH_DATA_FAIL)))
);
```

REDUCER:

```
     import { FETCH_DATA, FETCH_DATA_FAIL } from './constants';
     import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

     const initialState = {};

     export const exampleData = (state = initialState, action) => {
       switch (action.type) {
         case FETCH_DATA:
           return action.payload
         case FETCH_DATA_FAIL:
           return {};
         default:
           return state;
       }
     };

     export default combineReducers({
       exampleData
     });
```

EXAMPLE COMPONENT:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchData } from './actions';

class App extends Component {

  onClick = ()=>{
    this.props.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}><h1>Hello World</h1></button>
        {JSON.stringify(this.props.data) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    data: state
  }
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    fetchData: () => dispatch(fetchData())
  }
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

Comment: Since axios returns a promise do you need to use `.then` instead of `.map`?

Comment: Sure enough... That did the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `.then` would have solved the issue, by the right way of doing it is using rxjs's `from` function, like below

```
 import 'rxjs';
 import { FETCH_DATA, FETCH_DATA_FAIL } from './constants';
 import { fetchData  } from './actions';
 import axios from 'axios';
 import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
 import { mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
 import { ofType } from 'redux-observable';

 export const exampleEpic = action$ =>
   action$.pipe(ofType(FETCH_DATA),
   mergeMap(action =>
     from(axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'))
       .map(response => fetchData(response))
       .catch(error => Observable.ofType(FETCH_DATA_FAIL)))
);
```

Also, make sure you import `.map` operator from rxjs

**Update: syntax using the .pipe operator**

```
export const exampleEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(FETCH_DATA),
    mergeMap(action => from(axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1/'))
      .pipe(
        map(response => fetchData(response)),
        catchError(() => of(fetchDataFailure()))
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Hey, I have similar code but get `TypeError: Object(...)(...).map is not a function`. Using `"rxjs": "6.2.1"` and `"redux-observable": "^1.1.0"` any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This syntax is no more followed. There is a need of `.pipe()`  from `mergeMap` and then inside the `pipe( map() ....stuff )`

Comment: Siddhartha, Can you please share the new syntax which includes pipe, map and catch.